# IOC (simpleServiceLocator) setup testing with Specflow and WatiN

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, watin, specflow, service-locator

I have some acceptance tests using Specflow and WatiN but am not sure where to setup up my registrations for my IOC container (SimpleServiceLocator).

In my web site, the registration is done my global.asax.

In my test project, I've tried setting them up from my [BeforeScenario] method with code such as

```
var container = new SimpleServiceLocator();
container.Register<ISitecoreLookupAccessor>(
    () => new SitecoreLookupAccessor());

Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator
    .SetLocatorProvider(() => container);
```

And I get an object instance in my application project using

```
ISitecoreLookupAccessor accessor =
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISitecoreLookupAccessor>();
```

But I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." as ServiceLocator.Current is null ...

Answer (score 0):

The Global.asax is ASP.NET specific and will not run in your test project, because your test runner has no way of knowing that it should even consider the chance of having the possibility that their might be a global.asax :-)

In other words, for you to be able to use `ServiceLocator.Current`, the `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` should be called with a valid container for that test project. When using MSTest, there is an [AssemblyInitializeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that can be used to decorate a method. MSTest will in that case run that method before executing any of the test methods in that assembly. Other test runners have different mechanisms of doing this.

However, instead of configuring the Common Service Locator in your test projects, it is much better to prevent from using it completely in your tests. Instead inject all dependencies of a class under test in its constructor, and do that in the setup phase of each test (you can refactor the construction of such object under test to a special factory method for convenience). Prevent from calling the `ServiceLocator` from within the class under test (or any class in the application). This way there is no need of using the `ServiceLocator` in your test project. This will make writing tests so much easier, since you don't have to maintain the DI configuration in your test assemblies (and with multiple test projects, you would have had multiple DI configurations). I've walked this path and my DI configuration for my tests got horribly complex, especially since I had to deal with my test runner running my tests in parallel, which meant I had to inject mocks and stubs that were thread-safe (the horror!). But even without tests running in parallel, maintaining a test DI configuration is quite horrible.

Comment: Steven, Thanks for your suggestions... Im not able to use constructor injection as Im working with legacy code which can't (easily) be updated. When I call SetLocatorProvider from a method with the attribute AssemblyInititialize in the test project, ServiceLocator.Current is null in the project I am testing, presumably because it's a separate process but not sure what to do if I can't use constructor injection ...

Comment: Make sure the method decorated with [AssemblyInitialize] gets called. It should work, I did that in the past. You might need to look what the signature of such a method should be and where to exactly put it (in a class decorated with [TestClass] attribute for instance).

Comment: Here is book that might be interesting for you and your project: [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052).